# Finding matches for two connected fields with fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search a specific person by his given name and surname. I think the best option to search within two fields simultaneously is a bool query:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"match": {"name":"Martin"}},
                {"match": {"surname":"Mcfly"}}
            ]
        }
}
}
```

But bool queries don't seem to support fuzziness. So what could I do to find the person **"Marty Mcfly"** since this match isn't found by the above query. I also would like to be ably to find someone like **"Marty J. Mcfly"** if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool` is just a wrapper to join AND/OR/NOT/FILTER operations.

In your case it would make sense to use `multi_match` query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "multi_match":{
            "query":"Marty J. Mcfly",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields":[
              "name",
              "surname"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will search data in both `name` and `surname` fields and ensure that all terms must match in both of your fields.

#### Updated

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "Martin",
              "operator": "and",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "surname": {
              "query": "Mcfly",
              "operator": "and",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But this solution just searches "Marty J. Mcfly" in both fields and therefor wont give me results. I need something that looks for all similar names of "Marty" in name and "Mcfly" in surnames. The output should display those two fields of the same entity.

Comment: `match` queries support `fuzziness` option, adding this to your query should achieve what you wanted.

Comment: This might will include the correct match but it will also lead to a lot of false positive results because this query searches for surnames within the name field and for names within the surname field. For instance I was searching for "Martin Donovan" with fuzziness and I received "Barbara Marti-Donovan" as a result.

Comment: Aha, so your original query should be fine, just add fuzziness as a parameter to each match query.

Comment: Fuzziness doesn't seems to be support by bool queries for some reason. This is my main problem. If there's a way to combine them, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Try updated answer. Like I've said, fuzziness should stay in match query :)

Comment: Very nice, so it seems there is a syntactical way to combine it. Thank you.

Comment: Correct. bool query is used just to combine queries into AND/OR conditions, nothing else.